# SQL code for updating a column where the WHERE condition is from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, I have two tables: `WINE_TYPE` and `WINE`.

`WINE_TYPE` is the parent table, and `wtCode` is the primary key (foreign key in `WINE`).

I'm trying to execute code that will update the price of the wine (`winePrice`) by 50 cents, or 0.50. The catch is... my `WHERE` condition is from the parent table (I only need the wines that are made by the lead Amanda McPhee `(wtLeadFirst='Amanda', wtLeadLast='McPhee')` to be increased by 50 cents).

Inner join doesn't seem to work here. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax to update table with `JOIN` condition:

```
UPDATE WINE
SET WINE.WinePrice = WINE.WinePrice + 0.5
FROM
    WINE
INNER JOIN
    WINE_TYPE ON WINE.wtCode = WINE_TYPE.wtCode
WHERE
    WINE_TYPE.wtLeadFirst='Amanda' AND WINE_TYPE.wtLeadLast='McPhee'
```

Comment: I completely forgot the "FROM WINE" in my code, and that's where my error was...it would refuse to recognize inner join as proper syntax.  Thanks!  (I'm still fairly new to the program)

Answer (score 1):

`Update` + `Exists`

Use `Exists` operator to check the existence of `wtLeadFirst='Amanda'` and  `wtLeadLast='McPhee'` in parent table

```
update W
Set Wineprice = x + Wineprice 
from Wine W 
where exists (select 1 
              from wine_type WT 
              where W.wtCode =WT.code 
              and Wt.wtLeadFirst='Amanda' 
              and Wt.wtLeadLast='McPhee' )
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer purposely, if I did it by mistake then I apologize.

Comment: This anwser is stardard sql as apposed to the accepted answer which is SQL Server specific.